# Hibernate @OneToMany retrieve doesn't work

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a pretty standard Spring Data JPA / Hibernate @OnetoMany relationship that is persisting as expected, but when I select the parent, the children are not being retrieved.

Here is my parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APPOINTMENT")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "appointmentId")
public class Appointment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long appointmentId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appointment", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<AppointmentProcedureItems> appointmentProcedureItems = new ArrayList<>();

...
}
```

and then the child:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APPOINTMENTPROCEDUREITEMS")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
                  property = "appointmentProcedureItemId")
public class AppointmentProcedureItems {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long appointmentProcedureItemId;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "appointmentId", nullable = false)
  private Appointment appointment;
...
}
```

When I receive the appointment and nested appointmentProcedureItems as a DTO from the UI, I do this:

```
appointment.setAppointmentProcedureItems(appointmentProcedureItemsDTOConvertor.convertDTOListForOffice(dto.getAppointmentProcedureItemsDTO(), null, appointment));
```

...

```
public List<AppointmentProcedureItems> convertDTOListForOffice(List<AppointmentProcedureItemsDTO> dtoList,
                                                                            Office office, Appointment appointment) {

        List<AppointmentProcedureItems> appointmentProcedureItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (AppointmentProcedureItemsDTO dto : dtoList) {
            AppointmentProcedureItems item = convertAppointmentProcedureItemsDTO(dto, office);
            item.setAppointment(appointment);
            appointmentProcedureItemsList.add(item);
        }

        return appointmentProcedureItemsList;
    }
```

And I am just trying to retrieve as:

```
@Repository
public interface AppointmentRepository extends CrudRepository<Appointment, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Appointment>,
                QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Appointment> {

List<Appointment> findByOfficeIdAndStartDateTimeBetween(@Param("officeId") Long officeId,
                                                            @Param("startDateTime") ZonedDateTime startDateTime,
                                                            @Param("endDateTime") ZonedDateTime endDateTime);
..
}
```

and the called via service:

```
List<Appointment> foundAppointments = appointmentRepository
                        .findByOfficeIdAndStartDateTimeBetween(office.getOfficeId(), startAppointmentDate,
                                        endAppointmentDate);
```

Here is one of my tests:

```
def "create appointments, then try to change one operatory to be a conflict"() {
        def office = officeService.findByURL("myoffice")
        def startTime = LocalDateTime.of(2015, 11, 27, 11, 30)
        def maryApt = new Appointment(officeId: office.getOfficeId(), providerId: 10l, patientId: 1L,
                patientFirstName: "Mary", patientLastName: "Lamb" , title: Title.MISS,
                description: "test appointment #1 ", procedureId: 11l,
                startDateTime: DateUtil.convertToUTCZoneDateTime(startTime), endDateTime: DateUtil.convertToUTCZoneDateTime(startTime.plusMinutes(30)),
                operatory: new Operatory(id:1l, name: "operatory 1", officeId: office.getOfficeId(),employeeId:1l), employee: new Employee(fullName: "test Employee", office: office),
                appointmentDefinition: new AppointmentDefinition(appointmentDefinitionId: new Long(1L), officeId: office.getOfficeId(),
                        description: "test description", duration: 10, colorCode: "red",
                        providertype: AppointmentProvider.DENTIST))
        maryApt.getAppointmentProcedureItems().add(new AppointmentProcedureItems(appointmentProcedureItemId: 1L,
                providerId: 1L, procedureId: 1L, code: "One", description: "descript one", note: "note 1",
                price: new BigDecimal("1.0"), patientId: 1L))

       def maryAppointment =  appointmentService.saveAppointment(maryApt)

        def davidApt = new Appointment(officeId: office.getOfficeId(), providerId: 10l, patientId: 2L,
                patientFirstName: "David", patientLastName: "Lamb" , title: Title.MISS,
                description: "test appointment #1 ", procedureId: 11l,
                startDateTime: DateUtil.convertToUTCZoneDateTime(startTime), endDateTime: DateUtil.convertToUTCZoneDateTime(startTime.plusMinutes(30)),
                operatory: new Operatory(id:2l, name: "operatory 2", officeId: office.getOfficeId(),employeeId:1l), employee: new Employee(fullName: "test Employee", office: office),
                appointmentDefinition: new AppointmentDefinition(appointmentDefinitionId: new Long(1L), officeId: office.getOfficeId(),
                        description: "test description", duration: 10, colorCode: "red",
                        providertype: AppointmentProvider.DENTIST))

        appointmentService.saveAppointment(davidApt)

        maryAppointment.setOperatory(new Operatory(id:2l, name: "operatory 2", officeId: office.getOfficeId(),employeeId:1l))

        def maryDto = appointmentDTOConverter.convert(maryAppointment, office)

        expect:
        true == appointmentService.hasDuplicate(maryDto)
        maryDto.getAppointmentProcedureItemsDTO().size() == 1
        maryDto.getAppointmentProcedureItemsDTO().findAll {
            it.procedureId == 1L && it.code == "One" && it.note == "note 1" && it.description == "descript one" && it.officeId == office.getOfficeId() && it.patientId == 1L
        }.size() == 1

    }
```

I do not have any referential integrity on my tables, and I can inspect both tables and see that appointment is populated and the corresponding appointmentprocedureitems table is populated, with the appointmentId column with the correct appointment id in it.

I am surprised that the persist works but not the retrieve - don't know that I have ever seen this particular behavior before.  I have quite a few identical @OneToMany bidirectional relationships in this project, and to my eye all of them have the same mapping.

Comment: How do you determine that the items are not being retrieved? Do you have a test case? If so, what's its code? If not, how are you doing to determine that?

Comment: I have a integration test case that appears to work (against H2).  When running this via my app, I set a breakpoint in my service and inspect the appointment and see that its appointmentprocedureitem list is empty.

Comment: You chose a bidirectional one-to-many, but did you implement ['helper' methods](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/best-practices-many-one-one-many-associations-mappings/#highlighter_903)?

Comment: We can't really help without the code used to test this. My guesses are that 1. the debugger doesn't show you the actual stuff because Hibernate uses lazy proxies and/or you're creating items and setting their appointment, but forget to add them in the list of items of their parent appointments, and then load the appointments in the same session, leading to an empty list. The fact that your integration test passes is a sign that the mapping is not the problem, but that your disgnostic, or the business code, is the problem.

Comment: I just added the code how I convert from DTO to entity and set each object on the other.  Also adding an integration test.  If I understand correctly, the mapping is good but how I am setting each object on the other could be the issue?

Comment: I added the helper method on appointment that sets "this" on each appointment procedure item passed in.  Now I get a 'detached entity passed to persist: appointment.model.AppointmentProcedureItems'